# How do I use CALayer with the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

Currently, I have a UIView subclass that "stamps" a single 2px by 2px CGLayerRef across the screen, up to 160 x 240 times.

I currently animate this by moving the UIView "up" the screen 2 pixels (actually, a UIImageView) and then drawing the next "row".

Would using multiple CALayer layers speed up performance of rendering this animation?

Are there tutorials, sample applications or code snippets for use of CALayer with the iPhone SDK?

The reason I ask is that most of the code snippets I find that demonstrate simple examples of CALayer employ method calls that do not work with the iPhone SDK. I appreciate any advice or pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, well, if you want something that has some good examples of CA good that draws things like that and works on the phone, I recommend the [GeekGameBoard](http://mooseyard.com/Jens/2008/03/geekgameboard-getting-closer-to-iphone-ready/) code that Jens Aflke published (it is an improved version of some Apple demo code).

Based on what you are describing I think you are doing somthing way more complicated than it needs be. My impression is you want basically a static view that you are animating by shifting its position so that it is partially off screen. If you just need to set some static content in your drawRect going through layers is not going to be faster than just calling CGFillRect() with your color. After that you could just use implicit animations and the animator proxy on UIView to move the view. I suspect you could even get rid of the custom drawRect: implementation with a patterned UIColor, but I honestly have not benchmarked the difference between the two.

Answer (score 3):

What CALayer methods are you seeing that don't work on iPhone? Aside from animation features tied to CoreImage I have not noticed much that is missing. The big thing you are likely to notice is that all views are layer backed (so you do not need to do anything special to use layers, you can just grab a UIView's layer through the layer accessors methos), and the coordinate system has a top left origin.

In any event, generally having more things is slower than having fewer things. If you are just repeating the same pattern over and over again you are likely to find the best performance is implementing a custom UIView/CALayer/UIColor that knows how to draw what you want, rather than placing visually identical layers or views next to each other.

Having said that, generally layers are lighter weight than views, so if you have a lot of separate elements that you need to keep logically separated you will find that moving to layers can be a win over using views.

You might want to look at -[UIColor initWithPatternImage:] depending on exactly what you are trying to do. If you are using this two pixel pattern as a background color you could just make a UIColor that draws it and set the background.

Answer (score 1):

*What CALayer methods are you seeing that don't work on iPhone?*

As one example, I tried implementing the grid demo [here](http://devblog.brautaset.org/2008/10/01/calayer-grid-with-caconstraintlayoutmanager/), without much luck. It looks like `CAConstraintLayoutManager` and `CAConstraint` are not available in `QuartzCore.h`.

In another attempt, I tried a very simple, small 20x20 `CALayer` object as a sublayer of my `UIView`'s layer property, but that didn't show up.

Right now, I have a custom `UIView` of which I override the `drawRect` method. In `drawRect` I grab a context and render two types of `CGLayerRef`s:

At "off" cells I draw the background color across the entire 320x480 canvas.

At "on" cells, I either draw a single `CGLayerRef` across a grid of 320x480 pixels (initialization) or across a 320x2 row (animation).

During animation, I make a `UIImageView` clip view from 320x478 pixels, and draw a single row. This "pushes" my bitmap up the screen two pixels at a time.

Basically, I'd like to test whether or not using `CALayer` will accomplish two things:

1. Make my rendering faster, if `CALayer` has less overhead than what I'm doing now
2. Make my animation smoother, by letting me transition a layer up the screen smoothly

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get a basic CALayer working at the moment, and haven't found a good chunk of sample code to look at and play with.